# How do I programmatically select a tab using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile, tabs

I am new to jQuery 1.4.3 and Mobile 1.10 and would like to use the tabs widget. I am wondering how to programmatically make a tab active?

Please see the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lizhou/psfpm52w/). If I make the 2nd tab as active, the 2nd tab's content does not show until the 2nd tab is clicked.

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="tabs">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#one">one</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#two" class="ui-btn-active">two</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-content" id="one">tab one content</div>
        <div class="ui-content" id="two">tab two content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you not just click the element after adding an ID to the tabs themselves, using something like `id="tab-one"` and `id="tab-two"`, respectively, then using the following Javascript?

```
$('#tab-two').trigger('click');
```

Here it is in a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psfpm52w/1/).

Answer (score 2):

jQueryMobile bundles jQuery UI, so from the jQuery UI API docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

```
var tab_index = 1; // the zero based index of tab #two
$("div.tabs").tabs( "option", "active", tab_index ); // tab_index is zero-based
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a much of JQuery-Mobile guy, but [@Jeff's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3658230/jeff-n) code is all that is needed. I just added some code to make it dynamic: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/psfpm52w/2/).

Also you could refer to [this QA thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849019/jquery-mobile-navigation-tabs) for more info...

```
$(function(){

// Selectors
var tabs = 'div[data-role="navbar"]';
var tab = tabs + ' a';

// activate the selcted tab on load
activateTab();

// fetch the closest selected tab and trigger click
function activateTab(){
    var selected = $(tab).closest('.ui-btn-active');
    $(selected).trigger("click");
} });
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to activate a tab is not so easy when you use multiple pages and trasitions. During trasition the class "ui-btn-active" is removed.
So, if you want to select a tab before the page is dispalyed (eg pagebeforeshow), please use this function instead:

```
function selectTabInNavbar(tabs, nr){
    $( tabs ).tabs( "option", "active", nr );
    $( tabs + " [data-role=navbar] a" ).eq( nr ).addClass("ui-btn-active");
}
```

where `tabs` is the selector for the `<div data-role="tabs">` container, and `nr` is the number of desired tab (starting from index 0).

Answer (score 0):

See my full solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336233/jquery-mobile-default-tab/64080164#64080164) of all the issues I had to fix when using jQuery Mobile tabs!!